# UISearchController search bar shifting down when presented

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Issue: Searchbar shifts down when presented. Before presented, the bar is right below the navigation bar.

More Info:

- The navigation bar is just a UINavigationBar that's manually added to a UIViewController through storyboard
- Most importantly, the UIViewController uses UIPresentationController to create that effect where the presented VC is slightly offset from the top and the presenting VC is scaled down and "behind" the presented VC. The shift does not happen if I don't use a UIPresentationController.
- `searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO`

Any Ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
or 
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

On a side not it is probably better to add the searchbar to the header of the tableview.

Comment: Tried it and it still didn't work. The search bar is currently the header to the tableview. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
} else {
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
}
```

if you set searchBar to tableHeaderView under iOS 11.0 will cause this question, so you can do it like this. everything will be ok!